# Zend installation on Fedora 19

Tags: yum, fedora

I am trying to install Zend Server on Fedora 19. Once I run `yum install zend-server-ce-php-5.3` I get following error:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/local/zend/var/log conflicts between attempted installs of zend-server-php-5.3-common-6.3.0-19.x86_64 and mod-php-5.3-apache2-zend-server-5.3.28-1.x86_64
```

How can I fix the problem? I am following the instructions on the official zend installation documentation.